# What Method of False Discovery Rate do I have to implement for a Genome Wide Selection Screening?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, biostatistics, false-discovery-rate

I'm performing a Genome Wide Selection Screening on a panel of 7 cattle breeds genotyped by a 770k Illumina SNP array. The method is based on an Ohta statistic (D'^2is) which measures the between-population LD component: high levels of this statistic suggest that dispersive selection may have occured on a given genomic region.

The experimental D’^2IS values are computed for every pair of markers on each chromosome with equal or less than 99 markers between them.

However, D’^2IS is also influenced by other factors, so in order to remove these effects an empirical null distribution is performed with computed values of unlinked loci (pairs of SNP between different chromosomes), because they do not reflect the effects of selection but random factors such as sampling and genotyping error, population size, migration and mutation rate.

[image: Both Null and Experimental Distribution.]

The problem arises when i'm going to obtain a threshold value from null distribution to use it as criteria for filtering statistically significative experimental values. A total of 53,868,850 experimental SNP pair values had to be tested using a 54,000,000 Null values ditribution.

To account for the problem of multiple testing I implemented a False Discovery Rate analisis. I found at bibliography that for using an empirical null ditribution the BH procedure is not appropiate, so instead I stablished an arbitrary alpha level, found the Threshold value (T) in the Null ditribution as the 1-alpha quartile and estimate the associated FDR as the (Null values >= T) / (Experimental values >= T). For different alphas, the results were:

alpha = 0.01        T = 0.3042      FDR = 39,41 %

alpha = 0.005      T = 0.3372      FDR = 35,01 %

alpha = 0.001      T = 0.4311      FDR = 24,66 %

alpha = 0.0005     T = 0.4747      FDR = 18,78 %

alpha = 0.0001     T = 0.5817      FDR = 11,23 %

For example, with a T = 0.4747, a point plot for chromosome 11 is:

[image]

I have a few questions:

Is this FDR estimation method the most appropiate for this multiple testing problem? If we consider an alpha of 0.0005 (a highly strict level), we still have a 18 % of FDR. But, as we can see in the pointplot, is easy to distinguish peaks that are likely to be putative regions under selection and with a very strict statistic criterium are likely to be rejected as statistically significative. I don't know if there is a FDR estimation method that takes account of this clustering information of the statistic value.

What other FDR estimating methods could be useful for my study?

Also, the 29 autosomal chromosomes differ greatly in the number of experimental values. Should I consider independent 29 chromosomes and obtain 29 null distributions with different number of null values to do the multiple test correction with a size appropiate null distribution for each chromosome?

I apologize in advance, i'm still newbie at statistics.

Comment: To answer the second part of your question - you don't need 29 empirical nulls, because you don't expect the statistics to be different in each chromosome (they take into account only the nearby SNPs anyway, so it doesn't really matter how big the rest of chromosome is). However, the sex chromosomes might be differently selected, so I'd build a separate null for those, using marker pairs distant enough so that there'd be no LD. Something like 10 Mb separation should be enough.

Comment: btw, keep in mind that there's https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/, where you can ask questions specifically about tools for peak detection in genomics, for example.